# How to solve the error using the search bar filter and then unwind segue in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I currently have a screen in the mainPage(`viewController`) -> searchbarPage(`tableView in viewController`) -> subPage(`viewController`) order.

The subPage has a `back button` and uses the `unwind segue`. Then press the `back button` to return to the mainPage.

In the searchbarPage, select the `tableViewcell` without applying the filter, move it to the subpage, press the back button, and the unwind segue will work normally.

However, when I go to the subPage using the `searchbar` filter and press the back button, an error occurs.

I don't know why this is happening.

```
// Unwind Segue - mainPage
    @IBAction func gotoMainPage(_ sender: UIStoryboardSegue){
    }

// Search Bar filter - search Page
    func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
        if searchController.searchBar.text! == "" {
            self.filterSearch = self.MainDAO.find() // sqlite select
        } else {
            self.filterSearch = self.MainDAO.find().filter( {$0.itemName.lowercased().contains(searchController.searchBar.text!.lowercased()) }) 
        }
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the error you are getting?

Comment: @RikeshSubedi My error is' Application tried to present modal view controller on itself. Presenting controller is <UISearchController: 0x134823600>. '

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this code, it will help you it works for me

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) 
{
            searchController?.isActive = false // Add this !
            dismiss(animated: true)
}
```

Comment: Thanks. APP is not going to end. But when I select cell, the same screen comes out twice. Once again, performSegue is executed.

Comment: can you send me the code you have been Tried i will check it out

Comment: My didSelectRowAt code :
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            self.searchController.isActive = false
            self.searchController.dismiss(animated: false) {
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "subSegue", sender: self)
            }
    }